# Limit runtime for Amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, automation

What's a simple way for limiting runtime of an Amazon EC2 instance?     I'm getting runaway instances now and then which don't shutdown for various reasons.   These can cost a fortune.    Is there some sort of commandline flag which says the equivalent of "shut this instance down after 5 hours"?

Comment: How are you starting and stopping these instances right now?

Comment: right now my scripts halt it when my work is done,  but once in a while my control scripts crash and leave 'zombie' instances.   why was i downvoted??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK the Auto-Scaling service doesn't have this ability directly.

**EDIT: Although if you wanted you could create a group for auto-scaling, and set it to zero instances at a scheduled time - that way once that time is reached, all instances in the group would be shut down.**

But if you have any kind of automation involved for starting and stopping these instances, you can use a cron job, Windows scheduled task, or add a delay in whatever script you're using to launch these instances to execute the [ec2 instance shutdown command](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/starting-stopping-instances.html) after a specified time period:

```
PROMPT> ec2-stop-instances i-10a64379
```

or equivalently construct an HTTP request of the form:

```
https://ec2.amazonaws.com/?Action=StopInstances&InstanceId.1=i-10a64379&AUTHPARAMS
```

Another option you have would be to create the task on the AMI itself, so that whenever the instance was started it would shut itself down after 5 hours - this might be cleaner than an outside computer being responsible for it.

Comment: these are good ideas,  surprised there's no commandline flag but i'm going to do something like 'sleep 3600;  ec2-stop-instances....'

Comment: Trying to figure out why this was closed as off topic?   And no comment as to why?

Comment: I didn't vote it as off topic, but technically speaking this isn't really a programming question so much as a server management one. Next time maybe try asking similar questions over at serverfault.